# Register subset of Web API controllers with simple injector

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I'm manually registrering a subset of my project's Web API controllers:

```
container.Register(typeof(ILGTWebApiController), controllerType, Lifestyle.Transient);
```

Works fine. However, when I run:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

It seems to affect *all* Web API controllers in the project. I would like to leave the other ones untouched by simple injector.

If I don't run the code above, simple injector will complain about my controllers not having an empty constructor (which they obviously won't, since I'm using DI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing the `IDependencyResolver`, create a custom `IHttpControllerActivator` that resolves the controller or fallbacks to the original activator otherwise:

```
public sealed class MyControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly Container container;
    private readonly IHttpControllerActivator original;

    public MyControllerActivator(Container container, IHttpControllerActivator original)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.original = original;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(
        HttpRequestMessage req, HttpControllerDescriptor desc, Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(ILGTWebApiController))
            return (IHttpController)this.container.GetInstance(type);

        return this.original.Create(req, desc, type);
    }
}
```

You can configure your custom `MyControllerActivator` as follows:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
    new MyControllerActivator(
        container,
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerActivator()));
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, seems to work fine :) Followup question if you have time: When using this solution, is there any corresponding option to `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService`?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I used that snippet in an attribute class. I suppose one way to solve it would be to expose the `container` globally, so that it can be accessed from within the attribute. Is it considered bad practice to expose the container like that? I suppose one downside would be that it can't be 100% verified?

Comment: Sorry, you want to do what? What are you doing in an attribute and why?

Comment: In short, I want to access a container registration, let's say `container.Register<IFoo, Foo>()` inside an attribute class. Since I'm not able to use the attribute's constructor, I'm limited to property injector or a service locator, correct?

Comment: And why do you want to configure the container _inside_ an attribute. I would say that's an absolute no-no. The container should be configured in one place (the Composition Root) at one time (during startup).

Comment: Sorry, you're misunderstanding me here. It's not related to this topic. Perhaps it's better if I create a new topic. This is what I formerly was able to do: https://pastebin.com/QXUSHYzS. I don't want to configure the container in the attribute - I want to access one of its registered instances.