# Custom IHttpControllerActivator for MvcControllers

Tags: c#, simple-injector

Is there any way to register a custom `IHttpControllerActivator` for my Mvc controllers registered in simple injector, in a similar fashion to [what can be done with Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182026/register-subset-of-web-api-controllers-with-simple-injector)?

As soon as I run `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));`, simple injector hooks in to my third party controllers as well, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: In MVC, you would replace the default `IControllerFactory` implementation by inheriting from `DefaultControllerFactory`.

Comment: @Steven I see. Could you please provide a small example? Btw, this is not .net core

Comment: Take a look at the StructureMapControllerFactory in this article: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/27/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-controllers/.

Comment: @Steven Thanks. Please have a look at my suggested answer. As far as I can tell it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Steven's suggestions in the comments, I came up with the following:

```
public class MvcControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly Container _container;
    private readonly IControllerFactory _original;

    public MvcControllerFactory(
        Container container, IControllerFactory original)
    {
        _container = container;
        _original = original;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
        RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (controllerType == typeof(MyMvcController))
        {
            return (IController)_container.GetInstance(controllerType);
        }

        var controllerName = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
        {
            return _original.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        }

        return (IController) Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType);
    }
}
```

In my app start:

```
var original = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
var controllerFactory = new MvcControllerFactory(container, original);
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
```